The movie where housewife throws a knife into cockroach
I'm looking for the movie which:

Probably was for teens;
It rather was an English languge movie from the late 80s, or early 90s;
Contains the scene where the mother\housewife throws the knife over the kitchen and nails the cockroach to the fridge. She was some kind of secret agent. The husband is the witness of this scene.


I think it was a tomato, not a cockroach. This sounds like The Long Kiss Goodnight (1996).

Samantha Caine, suburban homemaker, is the ideal mom to her 8 year old daughter Caitlin. She lives in Honesdale, PA, has a job teaching school and makes the best Rice Krispie treats in town. But when she receives a bump on her head, she begins to remember small parts of her previous life as a lethal, top-secret agent. Her old chums in the Chapter are now out to kill her so she enlists the help of a cheap detective named Mitch. As Samantha remembers more and more of her previous life, she becomes deadlier and more resourceful. Both Mitch and Charly proceed to do the killing thing, the bleeding thing and the shooting thing. 





Man, beat by a matter of 30 seconds :(

Wow! Not cocroach but tomato, no late 80, but late 90. Yes, this is it. Memory is anyway volatile.

That's OK, mine too. Unless it's a movie I saw multiple times [Sorry steelerfan ;)].

All hail the "Great One" :)  +1

@KrzysztofDziądziak P.S. Your confusion is justified, though - at the very end, she kills a cricket with the same trick.
